# where to place H5P file using h5p-standalone plugin

Tags: html, file

I am trying to run xyz.h5p file using - https://github.com/tunapanda/h5p-standalone plugin.
I have created a 'workspace' directory and places .h5p files in that and trying run using 'test/simple.html' file that is available in package and modified the path in sample file like  -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const {
      H5P
    } = H5PStandalone;
    new H5P(document.getElementById('h5p-container'), '../workspace/xyz.h5p', {
      frameJs: '../dist/frame.bundle.js',
      frameCss: '../dist/styles/h5p.css'
    });
  </script>
```

can anyone let me know, what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be providing an H5P file inside the workspace folder that you specify.

H5P files are just ZIP files, and *h5p-standalone* expects the H5P file's/archive's contents inside the workspace folder, not the H5P file itself.

You will have to unzip your H5P file into your workspace folder first. The contents should then look similar to the contents in the [test workspace in the *h5p-standalone* repository](https://github.com/tunapanda/h5p-standalone/tree/master/test/full_workspace) meeting the [H5P file specification](https://h5p.org/specification).